# Three.js loading order

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with my Three.js Json-Loader. I have some object their path is saved in an array.
Now I want to load them and sort them in a List so that I can select them.
But the order they are loaded is a different than they are in my array after loading because they have different size so the small one are first and the bigger are last. So after loading them I don't know the name of the object ( the name is the path ).

My code :

```
for(var j=0;j<21;j++){
        var path = objPath[j];
        loader.load( path, function( geometry ) { save(geometry, path); } );
    }
```

with this code the path is given to the save methode but there is always the last (objPath[20]) path because the for-loop is faster than the loading methode.
What can I do that the path is the right?

Comment: i know that but i will have some thousand obj in the array and than it will take too long.

Comment: @Neil, did you mean synchronously as parallel and asynchronous are pretty much the same thing in this context? In any case, loading one after the other is a lazy person's solution (who doesn't want to find the real problem) and will increase the loading time.

Comment: I thought about that too but like tapio said I search for a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being bitten by a rather common mistake involving JavaScript closure rules, see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake). In short, to get the correct path passed to the save function, you need to wrap it into a helper function factory, like this: (or as shown in the above link)

```
function saveHelper(path) {
    return function(geometry) {
        save(geometry, path);
    }
}

for(var j=0;j<21;j++){
    var path = objPath[j];
    loader.load( path, saveHelper(path) );
}
```